# ConcurrentLinkedQueue: NotSerializableException

Tags: java, exception, serialization, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I need to serialize ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

```
public class Service implements Serializable { 
    private static Queue<Message> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(); 

    public class Serialize {
        public static Queue<Message> getMessages() 
        { 
            return messages; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Trying:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeObject(Service.Serialize.getMessages());
```

Result:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: server.Service$1    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.writeObject(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1430)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)

How to???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in this class which you have omitted to post you are using and trying to serialize an anonymous inner class, as the exception clearly states.

Comment: pride whete - you should un-accept my answer is it is totally incorrect.

Comment: The problem is - I don't have any anonymous classes.

Comment: Can you post the Message class definition.

Comment: Have 3 other collections with Messages and don't have any problems with them. 
public class Message implements Comparable<Message>, Serializable

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should get rid of the inner class Serialize and put the method inside of it in Service..

Comment: Why? It's not mentioned in the exception message.